# How can I have separate values within a textfield/text_area? and have the separate values entered into a database

Tags: html, sql, csv

For example Tumblr—and I think maybe WordPress—has a feature where you enter in tags and categories, respectively, and each one is entered into their database(maybe?) as separate values. Also if you know how to enter those same multiple values into a database row separated?

Sorry if this is something that's common sense to everyone else, I had to self-educate myself with this stuff and Google's not much help.

Bonus: A tutorial link would be greatly appreciated. Oh just realized the tag system on this site is similar also.

Is there also anyway the values could be more than just one word or is an unspaced string impossible within the same textfield/textarea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use any third party jquery plugins like

[jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

Other Resources include
[jquery-tokenfield demo](http://sbfaulkner.github.io/jquery.token-field/demo.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping it was basic javascript somehow like an attribute for input but I guess not.. I'll see what I can do with tokeninput man thanks

Comment: welcome man...if it has really helped you, then you can vote it.